# Get System Config Values in JS file without use of phtml

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs, jquery, system-config

I want to get System Config Value in my JS file directly **without using phtml template**.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As no one answer me, so I am gonna share my search link that help me out to fix that problem.
[how to add custom config provider](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110298/how-to-access-configuration-variables-in-magento-checkouts-javascript)

Other link to create custom config Provider is given below.
[How to create custom Config Provider](https://webkul.com/blog/create-custom-js-window-configproviders-magento-2/)

Above link will help you out to get system configuration values in your js file without use of phtml file.